# SAP DS is not pushing down ifthenelse or decode()

Tags: sap-iq, sap-data-services

I'm designing a DS JOB targeting a SybaseIQ and realize that IfthenElse Syntax and DI Decode() function are not getting pushed down to the database server.

Is there any equivalent DI function that I can use to push the whole operation down to Sybase IQ server ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently DS BODI won't be able to convert ifthenelse function to SybaseIQ's SQL format query if the database type is set to SybaseIQ in the datastore's setting.

If I change the database type to ODBC then the next thing I have to do is to change the option `ifthenelse support` to `Yes` and voila, the operation will be pushed down to SQL Server. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to edit the datastore's setting ... so I think I will have to cope with this until this issue is fixed by SAP then.